# Сохранить изменения в HTML документе

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую. Хожу вокруг да около, не могу понять одну вещь.

Есть кусок кода, добавляющий html-элемент в код, допустим:

```
 $('#content').append('<hr/>');
```

Этот код, как положено, добавляет линию в документ. Но при обновлении страницы эта линия опять исчезает. Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы добавленная разметка с помощью .append() сохранялась при перезагрузки страницы? Спасибо!

Comment: никак, при перезагрузке все строится заново, и если вы добавляли что-то руками после загрузки, то и после перезагрузки должны опять добавлять это руками

Answer (score 2):

```js
function appendText(){
    $('#text').val( $('#text').val() + 'text');
    $('#text').trigger( "change" );
};

function saveState(){
    localStorage["state"] = $('#text').val();
};

function loadState(){
    var state="";
    try {
        state = localStorage["state"];
    } catch ( e ){};
    $('#text').val( state );
};

$( document).ready( function(){
    $( "#button1" ).on( "click",  appendText);
    $( '#text'    ).on( "change", saveState );
    loadState()
} );
```

```css
textarea {width:100%; height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">
    Add
</button>
<br/>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Смысл весьма прост - храним значение в localStorage, а вообще можно хранить и на сервере- достаточно переписать функции сохранения и загрузки данных.